# Remove first n instances of a value from a column

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a macro that matches people with certain values in the column. However, part of the macro allows the user to remove a percentage of the People from the total each person has assigned to them. The data looks like this:

```
Data |   Name
--------------
1234 | Person1
3456 | Person1
8768 | Person2
0878 | Person3
4132 | Person5
0986 | Person1
0182 | Person5
0197 | Person4
4501 | Person2
4132 | Person2
8126 | Person4
0172 | Person4
0911 | Person4
0751 | Person3
6681 | Person1
8819 | Person2
```

The relevant parts of the macro so far looks like this:

```
Sub Load_Balancing()
Dim i as integer, j as integer, k as integer
Dim Vacay as string, Vacaypercent as string
Dim Person as Long, Person1 As long, Person1Int as Long, LastRowVacay as Long

Person = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B:B"), "=Person1")

For i = 3 To 18
    Vacay = Application.InputBox("Enter Name", "Enter full name",Type:=2) 
    If Len(Vacay) = 0 Then Exit For
    ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = Vacay
    Vacay = ""
    Vacaypercent = Application.InputBox("Enter percent reduction", 
"Enter % reduction", Type:=2)
    ws.Cells(i, 7).Value = Vacaypercent
    Vacaypercent = ""
Next i

LastRowVacay = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

For j = 3 To LastRowVacay
    Cells(j, 7).Value = (Cells(j, 7).Value * 0.01)
Next j

j = 0
For j = 3 To LastRowVacay
    On Error Resume Next
    If Cells(j, 6).Value = "Person1 Name" Then
        Person1Int = WorksheetFunction.Round(Person1 * Cells(j, 7).Value)
        k = 0
        For k = 3 To LastRowAssignments
'This is where the relevant code should go
    Else: Exit For
    End If
Next j
End Sub
```

Essentially, what I want is when the user puts in a person's name and the desired % reduction, the macro should remove that person's name that percent of the total assigned to them, leaving a blank cell in their place. For example, Person1 appears 4 times in the sample data. When the user types in Person1 and 50, the first two instances of Person1 should be removed from the list, leaving this:

```
Data |   Name
--------------
1234 | 
3456 | 
8768 | Person2
0878 | Person3
4132 | Person5
0986 | Person1
0182 | Person5
0197 | Person4
4501 | Person2
4132 | Person2
8126 | Person4
0172 | Person4
0911 | Person4
0751 | Person3
6681 | Person1
8819 | Person2
```

However, I am not sure how to go about this. I know I need to use a counter to be effective, but I cant figure out what form it should take. Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NLourme,
Something along the lines of the following should do the trick for you:

```
Sub test()
    Call killnValues("Person1", 2)
End Sub

Function killnValues(theText, n)
    Row = 0
    While x < n
        Row = Row + 1
        If Cells(Row, 2) = theText Then
            Cells(Row, 2) = Empty
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Wend
End Function
```

Obviously, you'll have to modify this accordingly to suit your needs which includes taking care to properly set the value of n. If the value of n exceeds the number of actual entries, an error will result. If you have any trouble implementing, just give a shout. Hope this helps.

Comment: That worked very well, thanks! I adapted it a bit because I actually have multiple values that need to be removed from the column, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Good luck with the rest of your project!